# Need to obtain the name of Global variable $_REQUEST

Tags: php

I need to obtain the identifier, name of Global variables. Eg. If I have $_REQUEST['email'] I need to obtain the word email within the $_REQUEST variable.

Comment: Please do not use the $_REQUEST array unless you are aware how it is put together and which security implications it poses. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear from this what you want. If you need a list of available keys in `$_REQUEST`, you can use `array_keys($_REQUEST)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will print every key with its value:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    print "{$key} => {$value}<br />";
}
```

Comment: Or you could just use `print_r($_REQUEST);`, or `var_dump($_REQUEST);`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
$k = array_keys($_REQUEST);
foreach($k as $v){
    writelog( "out.txt", $v); // The key name
    writelog( "out.txt", $_REQUEST[$v]); // the key value for the name
}
```

writelog is a simple log file function I use to help me debug and not essential to the answer.

```
function writelog( $logfilename, $description)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
    if (isset($_SESSION['loginID']))
        file_put_contents("out.txt", date("Y-m-d H:i:s ") . $description . " " . $_SESSION['loginID'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND );
    else
        file_put_contents("out.txt", date("Y-m-d H:i:s ") . $description . " NLO\n", FILE_APPEND );
}
```