# PHP - How can I write better code with E_NOTICES enabled?

Tags: php, e-notices

I prefer to develop with E_NOTICES turned on, but I often have to write excess, overly verbose, code when working with array indexes. How can I write this code in less code with E_NOTICES enabled.

With notices suppressed

```
if ($_REQUEST['some_key'] == 'bob')
{
}
```

Without notices suppressed

```
if (array_key_exists('some_key', $_REQUEST) && $_REQUEST['some_key'] == 'bob')
{
}
```

Comment: *(sidenote)* "What's wrong with using $_REQUEST" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request

Comment: *(tip)* `error_reporting(-1)` will will show every possible error (including `E_STRICT`), even when new levels and constants are added in future PHP versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally use [**`isset()`**](http://www.php.net/isset), instead of [**`array_key_exists()`**](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists), for that kind of thing ; which means using something like this :

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['some_key']) && $_REQUEST['some_key'] == 'bob')
{
}
```

A couple of differences :

- `isset` is a language construct, and not a function -- and its faster *(no function call)*
- note that `isset` will return `false` if a data is `null` ; `array_key_exists` will return `true`

  - But it's often not a problem, especially when dealing with GET/POST parameters
- it shorter to write (a couple less characters)

  - and you can use something like `if (isset($_REQUEST['a'], $_REQUEST['b'], $_REQUEST['c'])`, if necessary

Comment: I prefer array_key_exists() because isset() can't tell difference between NULL value and non-existant keys.

Comment: Thx Pascal for the robust answer. I think I'll stick to using an input/request library that allows for default values to be set on null/empty vars. ie, $w00lsworth = Input::get('the_var', 'default_value_if_not_passed');

Comment: @ZZ Coder: in what situations do you need to be able to tell the difference? I've never needed to do something with a variable that has been explicitly set to null.

Comment: @John : you're welcome :-) ;; of course, you are the one choosing the solution, in the end ;-)

Comment: @John using an abstraction for the Request is much better anyway, as it decouples you from the actual server environment. Can easily mock Requests this way.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way out is to use `@` for error suppression:

```
if (@$_REQUEST['some_key'] == 'bob') {}
```

However, this can be very slow if you're using it more than once or twice per page load.

Another solution is to assign your unknown by reference (although I'm not 100% sure this will work for superglobals like `$_REQUEST`):

```
$some_key =& $_REQUEST['some_key'];
if ($some_key == 'bob') {}
```

Generally, I just use `isset` like Pascal said.

Comment: I'd feel queasy looking at my code with @s splattered everywhere. It should be reserved for special use cases, and standout in your code (ie, if you're debugging a mysterious bug as a result of a suppressed message, it will be a pita, but at least it will be easy to find if it stands out in the code)

Comment: Also, silencing the error is about 4 times slower than calling isset()