# Collect data from <select> tag using PHP

Tags: php, search-engine

I tried to use the data from this form which is located in my main page - index.php.

```
    <center> 
<form action="search.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="search" size="30" /> 

<select name='wheretosearch'>
    <option value='Articles'>Articles</option>
    <option value='Users'>Members</option>
    </select>

<input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
</form> 
</center>
```

This is the main part of search.php code:

```
    include "all/config.php";

    $search = $_REQUEST['search'];  //Getting the words


    $split = split(" ",$search);  //If there is more than one I spit them.

     foreach ($split as $array => $value) 
{       $NewResult .= $value;
        }

    $wheretosearch = $_POST['wheretosearch'];

        if ($wheretosearch = 'Articles')
        {$Results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bgarticles WHERE title LIKE '%$value%' OR description LIKE '%$value%' OR text LIKE '%$value%' OR tags LIKE '%$value%' OR date LIKE '%$value%' OR author LIKE '%$value%' OR ip LIKE '%$value%' "); 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Results))
    { 
        echo "<div class='top'>";
        echo "<span class='title'>";
        echo "<a href=details.php?id=$row[id]>";
        echo $row['title'];
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</span> <br><br>";
        echo "<span class='author'>";
        echo $row['author'];
        echo "</span>";
        echo "<span class='date'> Date: ";
        echo $row['date'];
        echo "</span> <br><br><br>";
        echo "<br><br></div>" ;
        echo "<div class='bottom'><br><br></div>";
    } 
    }


        if ($wheretosearch = 'members') 
        {$Results2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username LIKE '%$value%' OR firstname LIKE '%$value%' OR lastname LIKE '%$value%' "); 

            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Results2))
    { 
        echo "<div class='top'>";
        echo "<span class='title'>";
        echo "<a href=details.php?id=$row2[id]>";
        echo $row2['username'];
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</span> <br><br>";
        echo "<span class='author'>";
        echo $row2['firstname'];
        echo "</span>";
        echo "<span class='date'> Date: ";
        echo $row2['date'];
        echo "</span> <br><br><br>";
        echo "<br><br></div>" ;
        echo "<div class='bottom'><br><br></div>";
    } 

        }
```

No matter I do it always shows data from both mysql tables. Why?

Comment: *(related)* [Should I change $_REQUEST to $_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987447/should-i-change-request-to-post/2987468#2987468)

Answer (score 4):

You're using a single equals sign, which sets a variable. A double equals compares.

```
if ($wheretosearch = 'members') {
// $wheretosearch is now (always) set to 'members'
// this will always trigger
}

if ($wheretosearch == 'members') {
// this will only trigger when the above is true
}
```

Comment: Same for the 'articles' check as well.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly: http://bobby-tables.com/

(and then check your `if`-clauses, you're using assignments (=) instead of comparisons (==))

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` instead of `=` in your `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

`=` != `==`

Your if conditions contain assignments, not comparison operations.

Common mistake, plenty of blogs contain easy ways to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an equal sign, so it's making an assignment instead of testing for equality.

```
if ($wheretosearch = 'Articles')
```

should be...

```
if ($wheretosearch == 'Articles')
```

Also: you're not escaping your queries, so your database would be easily hackable. Before using your variables in a query, escape them like so:

```
$wheretosearch = mysql_real_escape_string($wheretosearch);
```