# How can I retrieve HTTP Request data in Zend Framework MVC?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I know, there are many ways. I wish you could give me many ways to let me choose.

Comment: and I wish I had an elephant stamp

Comment: *(suggested reading)* [What is wrong with using `$_REQUEST`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request/2143042#2143042)

Comment: This is not a real question. When you already know there is several ways to achieve this, pick one and be happy. If you are unsure which to pick, clarify what makes you doubt. Express your concerns. Otherwise, use the simplest thing that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you're after but from a controller context, there's a couple of ways to access request parameters (note, this is not the same as `$_REQUEST`).

```
$param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param');
$param = $this->getRequest()->param; // provided the param name satisfies PHP object property rules for use in __get()
$param = $this->_getParam('param-name'); // same as above
```

From [`Zend_Controller_Request_Http::__get()`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php)

> Access values contained in the superglobals as public members
>   Order of precedence: 1. GET, 2. POST, 3. COOKIE, 4. SERVER, 5. ENV

What the comment does not mention is that it first checks the internal "instance" parameters array.

Answer (score 2):

From inside the controller you should use one of

```
$all = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$one = $this->getRequest()->getParam('key');

$all = $this->_request->getParams();
$one = $this->_request->getParam('key');

$all = $this->_getAllParams();
$one = $this->_getParam('key');
```

Or from outside the controller (and after the front controller is loaded)

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$all = $front->getRequest()->getParams();
$one = $front->getRequest()->getParam('key');
```