# jQuery $.ajax and php to delete a file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file

I'm trying to delete a file with jQuery's `$.ajax` and php. I have the following.

**/js/whatever.js**

```
$('.deleteimage').live('click', function() {
    $imagefile = 'http://domain.com/images/1/whatever.jpg';
    $imagethumb = 'http://domain.com/images/1/thumbnail/whatever.jpg';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'deleteimage',
            imagefile: $imagefile,
            imagethumb: $imagethumb,
        },
        url: 'script.php',
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    })
})
```

**/php/script.php**

```
<?php
    if($_GET["action"]=="deleteimage")
    {
        $imagefile = $_REQUEST['imagefile'];
        $imagethumb = $_REQUEST['imagethumb'];
        $imagefileend = '../images'.end(explode('images',$imagefile)); //This will get me the path to the image ../images/1/whatever.jpg without the domain which is the correct path to the file. I tried that path directly and it deleted the file. 
        $imagethumbend = '../images'.end(explode('images',$imagethumb));

        unlink($imagefileend);
        unlink($imagethumbend);
    }
?>
```

All path are correct. In firebug i see the post variables are being sent correctly to script.php, however files are not being deleted. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: check with if (file_exists($imagefileend)) { unlink($imagefileend); } else{echo "error";}

Comment: also, you're not echoing anything in php script, so you won't get the `msg` response in Ajax

Comment: I personally would post them all and use $_POST instead of $_GET and $_REQUEST in this condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery you use POST but in PHP you use GET. Change to `if($_POST["action"]=="deleteimage")` and please don't use `$_REQUEST` but `$_POST`

Comment: GREAT. That was exactly the problem. It's working now using POST. Do you know the reason why it wouldn't work with REQUEST.

Comment: This was what I said at the comment. This works because you are sending as POST. Also I suggest avoiding using $_REQUEST in anywhere in your script.

Comment: @Pinkie - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request

Comment: Yes i see why request is not a good idea. Thanks for the link.