# PHP - retrieve ajax posted json object in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using this function to send json to a php page:

```
function update_records(data) {
    data = data;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 2000,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: data, //'data='+data+'&aid=0',
        success: function() {
            success_message('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            failure_message('failure');
        }
    });
```

In firebug I can see the posted data:

```
[{
    "postid": 66,
    "values": [
        "field_key=a",
        "oldvalue=b",
        "newvalue=c dad"
    ]
}]
```

On my php page how can I `$_REQUEST` the object? Or am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: Something is strange in your request: You set contentType to "application/json" but send the data as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i actually did solve this one using this code on my js

this is how i collected my data
i have created the object

```
jsonObj={"postid":postid,"value":value};
var jsonString=JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

now i sent the object using ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: siteurl+'/wp-content/themes/crm/modules/update_lead.php',
  dataType : 'json',
  data: {action:actionType,data:data},
});
```

and this on the target PHP file ( /wp-content/themes/crm/modules/update_lead.php)

```
$json=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);
```

hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to decode your JSON string into an array.

Comment: problem is i get null when trying to $_REQUEST['data'] so json_decode is of course not working

Comment: Then something goes wrong in your posting. Also use `$_POST`. Then try adding this: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a neat function that allows us to read external and local JSON files.
[jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)( url, [data], [callback] )

The first parameter of this function, the URL you are planning to read, is required. The second parameter is used if you need to POST data to the URL. Last but no least, the callback function, although not required, is almost always necessary.

Comment: i want to figure out what im doinr wrong with my code :-) but thanks for the alternative

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should pass the data as "application/json" and not as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

```
...,
data: JSON.stringify(data),
...,
```

On the server side use [`json-decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the JSON encoded string into an object. This functions is very strict and relies on properly written JSON.

It tried it with the JSON you provided and it worked perfectly.
Example:
http://codepad.org/WOH2wGZv

I recommend to get rid of the surrounding square brackets if you pass only one object. I would also ensure the "values" are passed in JSON format instead of a string. This results in the following JSON:

```
{
   "postid":66,
   "values":{
      "field_key":"a",
      "oldvalue":"b",
      "newvalue":"c dad"
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On the PHP side, use `$_POST['postid']` to get '66', etc. If you used `type: 'GET'` in your AJAX query, you should've used `$_GET['postid']` on the PHP side.

Comment: the json object in my sample is with only 1 line in it i will have multiple id's in the future. i have tried using $_REQUEST['data'] but i get a NULL result.

Comment: That's because you won't get the javascript variable `data` in PHP. You only get the datas you send to it. Use `var_dump($_POST);` to see what exactly you're receiving on the PHP side. Also, don't use $_REQUEST : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2142754/851498

Comment: var_dump($_POST); returns array(0) {}
why not to use $_REQUEST ?

Comment: If var_dump returns array(0), then the problem is not in PHP. From what you're showing, I don't know where it is, though. See why not using $_REQUEST in the link I provided in my other comment :)