# Codeigniter 2.1.2 and Facebook-PHP-SDK 3.1.1

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I'm developing a simple authentication trough Codeigniter 2.1.2 and Facebook-PHP-SDK 3.1.1, but I have no idea why it's now working.

I've downloaded all files from the src folder (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src) into my libraries.

The login seems to be working, but when the user is redirected back to my website, the Facebook getUser() function always returns 0!

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Bloompit extends CI_Controller
{
    public $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('facebook', array(
            'appId' => '149275358530064',
            'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        ));
        $this->load->model('bloompit_model');
        $this->user = $this->session->userdata('user');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Bloompit';
        $data['page'] = 'home';
        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->user) {
            redirect(site_url(), 'location');
        } elseif ($this->facebook->getUser()) {
            try {
                $facebook_user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
                $this->session->set_userdata('user', array(
                    'name' => $facebook_user['name']
                ));
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                log_message('error', $e);
                redirect($this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                    'scope' => 'email',
                    'redirect_uri' => site_url('login')
                )), 'location');
            }
        } else {
            $data['facebook_login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email',
                'redirect_uri' => site_url('login')
            ));
            $data['title'] = 'Entrar';
            $data['page'] = 'login';
            $this->load->view('view', $data);
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        session_destroy();
        redirect($this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
            'next' => site_url()
        )), 'location');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can download the Codeigniter library for facebook connect here http://www.betterhelpworld.com/codeigniter/how-to-post-to-users-wall-on-facebook

Comment: I know there are some libraries for this, but I really would like to know why my code is not working. In fact, it worked a few times, but stopped and I have no idea why...

Answer (score 9):

The Facebook PHP SDK utilizes the $_REQUEST variable while CodeIgniter purges the $_REQUEST variable for security reasons.

To get around this, you may copy the content of $_GET to $_REQUEST before calling getUser():

```
$_REQUEST += $_GET;
$this->facebook->getUser();
```

Another solution would be to modify the Facebook PHP SDK to use $_GET instead of $_REQUEST.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a phenomenal find!!! I knew that my $_REQUEST was empty but couldn't figure out why! Thanks for the tip. I had no idea CI did this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using only function name in your site_url() function which is incorrect you must specify the controllers name.

Try this one:

```
$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email',
                'redirect_uri' => site_url('bloompit/login')
            ));
```