# Beginner to JSON and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Sorry about the simple question.

I am posting a JSON object to a PHP page using the following code:

```
    $.get("ProcessName.php", { name: "John" },
        function(data){
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
```

What code do I need to write in ProcessName.php to have the alert show the name is John?

I realise I could process the JSON object on the client but this is a simple example to help me understand how PHP pages read JSON objects sent from the client. I have ready many questions and beginner tutorials but they all seem to skip this simple step or maybe I am missing something.

Thanks,

Comment: all you would need is echo $_GET['name'];

Comment: well it may have cost me some reputation to find an answer but I really did not know how to do this. Thanks for your answer @Kris. I don't know why nobody explicitly stated this is what they were doing.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes, it is jQuery.

Comment: So then this question has nothing to do with JSON. Or POST. Please edit.

Comment: I am sure you know what edits you are talking about @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams but I have no idea. If you make the relevant changes I will approve them.

Comment: I can remove all references to "JSON" and replace "POST" with "GET", but then the final paragraph won't make any sense since it is very, very full of inaccuracies.

Comment: I don't see what's so inaccurate about the question. He only said "posting", not "POST", and `{ name: "John" }` is JSON, albeit very simple JSON. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I retagged it from json to jquery. I don't see what the big deal is

Comment: Thanks Kris and and Joe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your ProcessName.php page, to alert John all you would need is

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: No problem! I know when I first started AJAX it was all very confusing, but all the tutorials never seemed to explain the very basics and they just assumed you knew the basics.

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
 $.get("ProcessName.php", { name: "John" },
        function(data){
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
```

ProcessName.php:

```
<?php

if($_GET['name'] == "John") {
    echo "This work!";
}

?>
```

or sleep

```
<?php

sleep(200); 

if($_GET['name'] == "John") {
    echo "This work!";
}

?>
```

or

```
<?php

echo $_GET['name'] == "John" ? "At works" : null;

?>
```

for example :)
if you need append response to html use

```
$.get("ProcessName.php", { name: "John" },
        function(data){
            $("#append").html(data);
        });
```

your need create div id=append, for example! good luck!

Comment: This answer is good as well but I am going for the simplest answer as I deliberately asked this as a beginner question. Thanks for your help @johniek.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript/JQuery if you want to access JSON you can write

```
data.name
```

if you want to get the posted value on the page you can get it 2 ways

```
$_POST['name'];
```

and

```
$_REQUEST['name'];
```

you can also include the following statement

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
    echo "Name is ".$_POST['name'];
```

some people consider using $_REQUEST is bad practice, basically $_REQUEST checks the name in both $_POST and $_GET. To clear your concept you can [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request).