# PHP extract data from text file and write to another file

Tags: php

This is my first post on the internet for some assistance with coding so please bear with me!
I have been finding open code on the internet for a few years and modding it to do what I want but I seem to have come up against a wall with this one that I am sure is very simple. If you would please be able to help me it would be very much appreciated.

I have the following page:

```
    <?php 
    $text = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $f = file_get_contents("all.txt"); 
    $f = explode(", ", $f); 

    function modFile($pos, $tothis, $inthis)
    { 
        foreach($inthis as $pos => $a){ 
        } 
        $newarr = implode("\r\n", $inthis); 
        $fh = fopen("example.txt", "w"); 
        fwrite($fh, $newarr); 
        fclose($fh); 
    } 

    modFile(4, '', $f);
```

I have a file (all.txt) with the following:

```
    11111111111, 22222222222, 33333333333, 44444444444
```

That I wish to display like this:

```
    11111111111 
    22222222222
    33333333333
    44444444444
```

and to add a space then some text after each number where the text is the same on each line:

```
    11111111111 text here
    22222222222 text here
    33333333333 text here
    44444444444 text here
```

I have an html form that passes the custom text to be appended to each line.
I need to keep the file all.txt intact then save the newly formatted file with a different name.

I have tried putting variables into the implode where I currently have the "\r\n" but this does not work.

Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps a database is more suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes about your code: You are passing `$pos` to the function but it will get overwritten in the `foreach`. Also the `foreach` is empty, so what's it good for? And I don't see you use `$text` anywhere either.

To achieve your desired output, try this instead:

```
file_put_contents(
    '/path/to/new.txt',
    preg_replace(
        '/[^\d+]+/',
        ' some text' . PHP_EOL,
        file_get_contents('all.txt')
    )    
);
```

The pattern `[^\d+]+` will match any string that is not a consecutive number and replace it with "some text " and a new line.

A somewhat more complicated version achieving the same would be:

```
file_put_contents(
    '/path/to/new.txt', 
    implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(
        function ($number) {
            $message = filter_var(
                $_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS
            );
            return sprintf('%s %s', trim($number), $message);
        },
        array_filter(str_getcsv(file_get_contents('/path/to/all.txt')))
    )
));
```

This will (from the inside out):

- Load the content of all.txt and parse it as CSV string into an array. Each array element corresponds to a number.
- Each of these numbers is appended with the message content from the POST superglobal ([you dont want to use REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request)).
- The resulting array is then concatenated back into a single string where the concatenating character is a newline.
- The resulting string is written to the new file.

In case the above is too hard to follow, here is a version using temp vars and no lambda:

```
$allTxtContent = file_get_contents('/path/to/all.txt');
$numbers = array_filter(str_getcsv($allTxtContent));
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$numbersWithMessage = array();
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $numbersWithMessage[] = sprintf('%s %s', trim($number), $message);
};
$newString = implode(PHP_EOL, $numbersWithMessage);
file_put_contents('/path/to/new.txt', $newString);
```

It does the same thing.

Comment: Gordon, Many thanks for this - it works! It does however leave one further instance of the message text at the end of the file. Any ideas? Maybe there is an extra space kicking around somewhere. In relation to my code, as I say I was modding existing code I found and left some bits in that were obviously not necessary. I thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: @user1592162 there is probably a dangling comma after the last number in all.txt. Either remove it or put an `if` into the anonymous function checking whether `$number` is empty or put an `array_filter` around the `strgetcsv` call.

Comment: Cheers. Is it possible to have a second variable passed to the script from the html form called 'time'? I need to modify the path of the place where the new file is stored to include the time eg: folder/$time/example.txt  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @user yes, easily. after you made sure that $time is in the desired format, just change the path to the new file to read `"/path/to/folder/$time/example.txt"`

Comment: I tried that before I asked but it won't pull across the variable from the html page. Do I call it with $time = $_REQUEST['time']; ?  I am not using php to get the time as the user is entering the hour at which something is to be filed to be called later you see. Hope this makes sense - thanks again!

Comment: I have tried the following with no success:    <?php
$time = $_POST['time'];
file_put_contents(
    '$time/example.txt', 
    implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(
        function ($number) {
            return sprintf('%s %s', trim($number), $_POST['message']);
        },
        str_getcsv(file_get_contents('all.txt'))
    )
));
?>   Sorry can't seem to format the code correctly in this comment box.

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents($time/example.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\sms\create_schedule.php on line 11    It seems that the value of the variable is not displaying but the name or it ($time) is. Thanks again for your help - it is much appreciated!

Comment: @user1592162 change the single quotes to double quotes. you want to do [string interpolation](http://de2.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach() closing brace is on the wrong place. You've missed the exact part of running the execution of the new file creation. Here:

```
$text = $_REQUEST['message'];
$f = file_get_contents("all.txt"); 
$f = explode(", ", $f);
function modFile($pos, $tothis, $inthis, $text){ 
    $fh = fopen("example.txt", "w");
    foreach($inthis as $pos => $a){ 
        $newarr = $a." ".$text."\r\n";
        fwrite($fh, $newarr);
    }
    fclose($fh);
} 
modFile(4, "", $f, $text);
```

This is for formatting your new file as you desire, however, you're not passing the new $text['message'] you want to append to your new file. You could either modify your mod_file() method or pass it within the foreach() loop while it runs.

EDIT* Just updated the whole code, should be now what you aimed for. If it does, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: there is no point in passing `$pos` to `modFile` when you overwrite it in the `foreach`. Also newlines are platform dependent. You will want to use `PHP_EOL` instead.