# Unable to get request parameters in php

Tags: php

I am using the following code to get data from `$_REQUEST` in php:

```
for($i=0;$i<intval($q);$i++)
    {
       $construct="'".$i."'";
       echo $construct;
       $p=$_REQUEST[$construct];
       echo $p;

    }
```

where '0','1',... so on have values. But for some reason it does not work. However if I replace it by $_REQUEST['0'] it seems to print the value fine. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there is a parameter with name `0` passed?

Comment: Definitely sure. If i say echo $_REQUEST['0'], it prints the value.

Comment: *(related)* [What's wrong with using `$_REQUEST`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$construct` variable's value contains single quotes, which are not necessary. When you write it out as `'0'` you are indicating an actual value of `0`, whereas `"'0'"` indicates a value of `'0'`. Your code should read:

```
for($i=0;$i<intval($q);$i++)
{
   $construct= strval($i);
   echo $construct;
   $p=$_REQUEST[$construct];
   echo $p;
}
```

or more simply:

```
for ($i=0; $i<intval($q); $i++) {
   echo $_REQUEST[strval($i)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around `$i`:

```
for($i=0;$i<intval($q);$i++)
{
   $construct=$i;
   echo $construct;
   $p=$_REQUEST[$construct];
   echo $p;

}
```

This is because the quotes are not part of the array indexes.

Besides, if you want to debug, you could write out the entire contents of the `$_REQUEST`-variable like this:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
print "</pre>";
```

**EDIT:**

`$a[$b]` is the same whether `$b=0` or `$b='0'` or `$b="0"`, but not when `$b="'0'"`.

Comment: @xdazz - you are correct, but the code in the question would actually equate to `$_REQUEST["0"] != $_REQUEST["'0'"]` or to use all single quotes `$_REQUEST['0'] != $_REQUEST['\'0\'']`

Comment: @xdazz I agree with doublesharp here. See my added line under EDIT.

Comment: @poplitea Yes, that's the issue.