# can't get the value from url using php

Tags: php

everyone here ..
now i got an problem , so please help me , because I am new with php code. I want to get value from url but the result is Undefined index

this is url : http://4you4me.com/admin/index_edit_form.php?edit=76

php code :

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['edit']) === TRUE && ! empty($_REQUEST['edit']))
        $con_id_update = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_REQUEST['edit']);
print_r($con_id_update);
```

The result is undefined Variable:con_id_update

what is wrong with this script? thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the curly braces:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit']) === TRUE && ! empty($_REQUEST['edit'])) {
    $con_id_update = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_REQUEST['edit']);
    print_r($con_id_update );
}
```

If you don't wrap the curly bracers around the entire statement, only the line after the if statement will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$con_id_undate ='';// to initialize 

 if(isset($_GET['edit']) && !empty($_GET['edit']))
            $con_id_update = (int)$_GET['edit'];

    print_r($con_id_undate);
```

You shouldn't use [$_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2142754/1427338)

Also you should use msqli instead of mysql. Since you cast the value to an int you don't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

mysql_real_escape_string *(**mysqli**_real_escape_string)* tends to work only when their is already an open connection

Comment: why you recommenced me, shouldn't use $_REQUEST ? bleuscyther .

Comment: after changed it no result response on net tab in firebug .No value available.

Comment: let's me try to solve it anyway thank you for your kind . really thank you . good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should get value from url using $_GET instead of $_REQUEST if you know exactly what you want, good luck!