# Undefined Index error. Whats wrong in this?

Tags: php

Need some help with a simple php code. When I try to access http://example.com/login.php, it gives me a warning "Notice: Undefined index: type in www.example.com on line 2". But, when Try to access http://example.com/login.php?type=InvalidLogin, everything works fine. Whats wrong in my code.

My Code:

```
<?
$type = $_REQUEST["type"];
if ($type == 'InvalidLogin') {
?>
Your login is invalid.

<?
} else {
?>
Your login is valid
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: There is 1830 results for [Notice: Undefined Index](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Notice%3A+Undefined+index+%5Bphp%5D) in addition to the thousand of results a search engine will give you. I don't see anything in your question that warrants asking this yet another time. Please do research before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and do the following:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET["type"]))
  {
     $type = $_GET["type"];
     if ($type == 'InvalidLogin') {
        echo "Your login is invalid.";
     } 
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Your login is valid";
  }

?>
```

Comment: because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request

Answer (score 1):

```
$_REQUEST["type"]
```

is requesting data from url http://example.com/login.php?type=InvalidLogin. If there isn't type, it gets error cannot find 'type'.

And dont use $_REQUEST to get the data. use $_POST or $_GET

Comment: no use $_GET in this instance, its from a query string

Comment: @allen213 $_GET can use for query strings. Isn't it?

Comment: Question implies us of a query string and $_GET is for that.

Answer (score 0):

you should use isset ($_REQUEST["type"]) to test the index