# PHP form not submitting but not showing any errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contact-form

I am trying to set up a really simple coming-soon page with a contact form. I have uploaded everything [here](http://oceansouldiers.com/test/) (click *contact us now* button).

Now, when I fill in the information and click send, it will give me an error message. I can't see anything wrong and have error reporting set to on (maybe on the wrong place), here's the php code:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);


if (isset($_REQUEST['name'],$_REQUEST['email'])) {

    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $to = 'editedforstackoverflow';

    $subject = 'Contact Request From Website';
    $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";

    $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    echo ($send_email) ? 'success' : 'error';

}

?>
```

And here the js part:

```
    $('#ajax-contact').on('submit', function() {

    // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
    $('.output_message').text('Loading...');

    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        method: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == 'success') {
                $('.output_message').text('Nachricht erfolgreich geschickt!');
            } else {
                $('.output_message').text('Da ist leider ein Fehler unterlaufen!');
            }
        }
    });

    // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
    return false;
});
```

I can't really see what error I made, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your form in your site, it seems your `<input>` tags are missing those `name` attribute on the `name` and `email` fields:

[image]

They need to have that `name="name"` and `name="email"` so that `.serialize()` could get those values and bring them into your request. So that in turn in PHP, they'll be inside your `$_REQUEST`

Here's a demo on what I mean on those missing `name=""`. I've explicitly omit field 3 so that you can see.

http://codepad.viper-7.com/rTTPuq

So the fix is. Just add `name="name"` and `name="email"` on those `<input>` tags.

Actual note in the [manual](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a **name attribute**.

Comment: Thank you! That is when you focus too much on making it look fancy rather than making it work :)

Comment: @Paranoia yeah, you totally forgot about that `name=""` glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

your if statement is totally wrong.
you can't separate 2 statements with `,` ,it should be separated with `||` or `&&`.
[The Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) article will get you familiar with these operators.
also, `$_REQUEST` is very insecure.its best not to use them.the reason for not using them is explained [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request).