# null values on $_post

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to create a basic input form to record new clients to a MariaDB table but my post results are coming back null.

The form for entry is set as below

```
<form class="clientreg" id="NewClient" method="post" action="posttest.php">
    <label>Client Name:
        <input type="text" name="ClientName" class="LongText"/>
    </label>
    <label>Bulk Discount: <input type="number" name="Bulk" class="discount"/></label>
    <label>Settlement Discount: <input type="number" name="settlement" class="discount"/></label>
    <label>Trades Discount: <input type="number" name="Trades" class="discount"/></label>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

`print_r($_POST)` returns `Array()` so the information is not being picked up on submission. I've checked the obvious issues that come up ie no `name=' attributes` and correct encasing, but I'm at a complete loss

Comment: Welcome to SO. Add your PHP code so we can help

Comment: Hi, first check your action  page path is correct and put print_r($_POST) on first line of your posttest.php page

Comment: where did you put print_r($_POST) code ? is it on  posttest.php page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your PHP script *posttest.php*. Your form seems to be ok.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<title>just for test</title>
</head>
<div id="Response" ></div>
<h3>login</h3>
<form class="clientreg" id="NewClient" method="post" action="posttest.php">
    <label>Client Name:
        <input type="text" name="ClientName" class="LongText"/>
    </label>
    <label>Bulk Discount: <input type="number" name="Bulk" class="discount"/></label>
    <label>Settlement Discount: <input type="number" name="settlement" class="discount"/></label>
    <label>Trades Discount: <input type="number" name="Trades" class="discount"/></label>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### posttest.php

```
<?php
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    echo "\$_POST[$key]=$val<br />";
}
?>
```

### Result

```
Array
(
    [ClientName] => MyName
    [Bulk] => 1
    [settlement] => 2
    [Trades] => 3
)
$_POST[ClientName]=MyName
$_POST[Bulk]=1
$_POST[settlement]=2
$_POST[Trades]=3
```

Comment: I swapped my posttest.php code

    <?php print_r($_POST) ?> 

With the one you wrote and it was giving the same null return so it wasn't a code issue.

PHPstorm was outputting to browser using localhost:63342 instead of 8080. Just need to reconfigure

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your HTML script. I think you are trying to refresh your posttest.php file without running your form (like without form resubmitting).
if that is not the case just share your posttest.php code. 
*You can also use `$_REQUEST` which capable of dealing with `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables:*

```
 <?php
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($_REQUEST);
     echo "</pre>";
   ?>
```

Comment: fyi : [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request)