# Getting values from a form using $_REQUEST and then echoing them, but I'm getting a strange extra value

Tags: php

Edit: This was a very specific question but a more general response to using $_REQUEST was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request). Solved!! Thanks @u_mulder and @FirstOne!

Just starting PHP and running through some exercises from PHP & MySQL: The Missing Manual. They have me build this form:

```
<form action = "scripts/showRequestInfo.php" method = "POST">
            <fieldset>
                <label for "first_name">First Name:</label>
                <input type  = "text" name = "first_name" size = "20" /><br />
                <label for "last_name">Last Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "last_name" size = "20" /><br />
                <label for "email">E-Mail Address:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "email" size = "50" /><br />
                <label for "facebook_url">Facebook URL:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "facebook_url" size = "50" /><br />
                <label for "twitter_handle">Twitter Handle:</label>
                <input type = "text" name = "twitter_handle" size = "20" /><br />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class = "center">
                <input type = "submit" value = "Join the Club" />
                <input type = "reset" value = "Clear and Restart" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

The PHP script in the page it accesses is this:

```
<?php
            foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
                echo '<p>For ' . $key . " the value is " . $value . '</p>';
            }
        ?>
```

The list of key and value pairs I get seem normal, except for one extra at the bottom that I can't see anywhere in the code:

**For SQLiteManager_currentLangue the value is 2**

This appears in chrome, but not firefox. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because `$_REQUEST` stores values of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`. And it's not recommented to use it. If you have `post` - use `$_POST`, `$_GET` - use `get`.

Comment: [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2142497/4577762)

Comment: @FirstOne for example it can lead to anomalies like the one mentioned by op that means that what your code will output is not what you expect. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @LelioFaieta, not that, I mean, I should've explained a bit more xD. That link is supposed to show that to the OP. There is no need to rewrite what's mentioned by u_mulder's comment. I just thought of linking some more reading...

Comment: Ups! Missed the link from mobile ;) @FirstOne

Comment: Thanks for the answer @u_mulder !

Comment: Great link @FirstOne