# Post data to URL without form

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to post data to my url but the form is not recognising anything being posted.

http://localhost/webpanel/createkeys.php?pcname=joe&username=guessme

so surely in the code below the $post values should be stored?

```
$_POST['pcname'];
$_POST['username'];
```

But when I load that url I posted I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'pcname'
>   cannot be null' in

The rest of the code is posted below, it is a short php file but cannot work out the issue.

```
<?php


// if(!isset($_POST) || empty($_POST['pcname'])) {
//  exit;
// }

$pcname = $_POST['pcname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

include 'db.php';
$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO dummy (pcname, username, privatekey) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

$stmt->execute([
    $pcname,
    $username,
    $privatekey
]);
```

Comment: can we see your form?, mabe your not using POST method

Comment: I see you have your parameters in URL, are you sure you don't need to use $_GET instead of $_POST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use $_GET instead of $_POST :

```
$_GET['pcname'];
$_GET['username'];
```

Comment: Ah really? I thought because I am posting the data in the url ... I had to use POST silly me :/ thankyou for that,. didn't realise GET is used when not using form

Comment: Alternatively `$_REQUEST` will contain a combination of the two (with a order preference), but it's often seen as bad practice for whatever reason. _(edit: oh yeah [the cookie factor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request))_

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez of course but I have to wait 7 minutes, I feel silly for not knowing this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$_GET, you bold use $_REQUEST which holds both but this is commonly bad practice.

You can simulate $_POST by performing a Curl request within php.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: thanks for that :) I should of researched that thanks!