# How to open main page with parameters

Tags: php

My question may be very simple question. I am new in php. I searched but I couldn't find the best answer. My main page is index.php. When the page is loaded I want to run the main page with parameters. For example index.php?simple=1.

Comment: `$_REQUEST`is your friend. But since you are learning PHP from scratch, do yourself a favour and [learn about routing](https://www.google.de/search?q=php+routing&oq=php+routing), instead of messing with files.

Comment: "$_REQUEST or not $_REQUEST, that is the question" - Shakespeare-

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez, had you added the link: [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request) then your comment would be fun and very appropriate :)

Comment: I feel that there is more to this question than meets the eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two files :

**index.php**

```
<?php
header( "Location: main_page.php?simple=111" );
?>
```

**main_page.php**

```
<?php
echo $_GET[ "simple" ];
?>
```

`index.php` will call `main_page.php` with the parameter you want.

@Fred-ii- is right, this is the fix for main_page.php :

**main_page.php**

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET[ "simple" ] ) )
   echo $_GET[ "simple" ];
?>
```

Comment: accessing main_page.php directly will throw an error, should someone fool around with the parameters.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, fixed! (thanks). More should be handled about parameters, but that's for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$_GET` superglobal.

```
if ($_GET['simple'] == '1')
{
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to run index.php?simple=1 directly. For example I am working on localhost. When I run my project. it is working localhost/index.php. I can't send any parameter. I want to run localhost/index.php?simple=1. İs it possible or what should I do?

Comment: I don't understand why it wouldn't let you do that, encoding it into the URL should work.

Answer (score 0):

you must check if the variable is set first, then get the value (do you can display the page without parameters.. like that:

```
    if(isset($_GET['simple'])){
        $simple=$_GET['simple'];
        //now simple is the value of parameter 'simple';
        }
```