# Do not Access Superglobal $_REQUEST Array Directly

Tags: php, netbeans, sqlsrv, superglobals

I have until now been accessing $_REQUEST in my PHP as follows:

```
//JS
xmlhttp.open("GET", "logic.php?q=" + itemOne  + "&w=" + itemTwo, true);

//PHP
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];
$w = $_REQUEST['w'];
```

The items being sent through get used for MSSQL server queries (SQLSRV).

**My question is what would be the best-practice methods for doing the above differently/correctly?** I read somewhere that this is not good in terms of being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks etc.

Comment: it's totally ok with using $_REQUEST. you have to take care with queries. simply use ajax get/post request for it.

Comment: It's not possible to tell from that code if it's vulnerable or not to sql-injection. But take a look at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: A side note is to use the 'correct' global according to the request. If you are seding a `post`, access the variables from `$_POST`, if `get`, then `$_GET`. Take a look at [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what would be the best-practice methods for doing the
>   above differently/correctly?

The example JavaScript you gave used a `GET` request. The "correct" way to access the parameters would be through PHP's `$_GET` array.  Using `$_REQUEST` is a bad habit because you lose control over how the data arrived.  I'll give you a simple example:

Websites that use token base authentication often require that you send the token as `POST` data. If it is considered insecure to exchange private info through URL parameter, a PHP script that gets the data from `$_REQUEST` has no way to know how the data arrived, and will mistakenly accept a badly sent token.  A better script would look for the token in `$_POST`.  If it's not there, then there is no token; even if a user tried to send it in the url.

> I read somewhere that this is not good in terms of being vulnerable to
>   SQL injection attacks etc.

SQL injection doesn't have to do with `$_REQUEST` specifically.  It can occur whenever you insert user submitted data directly in your SQL queries, whether the data came from `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET`, a file... This terrible code design allows an attacker to take control of your SQL and instruct your DB to execute whatever command he or she wishes (eg: to exfiltrate or delete your data). To protect yourself against it, learn about *prepared statements* and *parameterized queries*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will look into the correct usage of `$_GET` array.

Okay I think luckily from a SQL injection point of view then I should be okay as I have: a) full up front JS field validation before it reaches this point to get data in line with what I want b) I use prepared statements with only parameters c) the MSSQL user I use to log in with may only read data from the DB.

Comment: If my solution answered your question, select it!  :-)  You should think as front-end validation as a convenience service for the user, not a security feature for the server. This is because it's really easy to send http requests to your server using bad parameters without ever using your front-end site.

Comment: Thanks! I will do so! Just in terms of using `$_GET` correctly does the below look better?

`$_GET["q"] = $q;
$_GET["w"] = $w;`

Comment: It's usually the other way around. Not `$_GET["q"]=$q` but `$q=$_GET['q']` because you're trying to read the values that PHP placed in `$_GET` when the browser sent data to the server, and save those values in local variables (eg: `$q`)

Comment: When I do that Netbeans says: `Do not Access Superglobal $_GET Array Directly.

Use some filtering functions instead (e.g. filter_input(), conditions with is_*() functions, etc.).`

Comment: That's not a message from PHP. It's your code editor trying to get you to build good habits. It's a good reminder that you should treat incoming data as untrusted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117616/discussion-between-user3324415-and-beetlejuice).