# Issue with placeholders not selecting data

Tags: php, sql

Im creating an script that selects data from a data table and then shows all the information from that row of data and allows you to edit the text. Currently there is no information appearing in the boxes:

[image: Here is what the data table looks like currently]

[image: Here is what the data should look like, as you can see the information should already be present but it gives you the option to edit the file.]

So there are 3 files:

---

File Number 1: Typing in the ID Number:

```
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<form method="post" action="export1.php">
Enter ID:<input type="Text" id="id" name="id"><br>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit ID" value="Submit">
</form>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

File Number 2: Option to edit the data:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("somedb", "someuser", "somepassword");
mysqli_select_db($db,"leadlist");
$id=$_POST['export'];
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `leadlist` WHERE id=$id");

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['id']);
$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['fname']);
$sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['sname']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['address']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone']);
$package = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['package']);
$active = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['active']);
$mac = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['mac']);

?>
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="userscript.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="textentryhead">
        <h1>Reave</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="textentry">
    <div>
        <form action="exportcode1.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name :</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="<?php echo $fname ?>" id="fname">
        <hr>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name :</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="sname" placeholder="<?php echo $sname ?>" id="sname">
        <hr>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Address :  </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="<?php echo $address ?>" id="address">
        <hr>
    </p>
     <p>
        <label for="firstName">Email Address :   </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $email ?>" id="email">
        <hr>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Phone Number :</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="<?php echo $phone ?>" id="phone">
        <hr>
    </p>
      <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Package Type :</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="package" placeholder="<?php echo $package ?>" id="package">
        <hr>
    </p>
      <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Package Status :</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="active" placeholder="<?php echo $active ?>" id="active">
        <div id="help"><h6><a href="help.php">Help</a></h6></div>
        <hr>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">MAC Address :</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="mac" placeholder="<?php echo $mac ?>" id="mac">
        <hr>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

File Number 3: Adding the new data into a different data table:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['fname']);
$sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['sname']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['address']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone']);
$package = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['package']);
$active = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['active']);
$mac = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['mac']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO CData (fname, sname, address, email, phone, package, active, mac) VALUES ('$fname', '$sname', '$address', '$email', '$phone', '$package', '$active', '$mac')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

                mysqli_close($conn);
                header("Location: ");




                exit;

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close(
```

So if someone can help me get this working it would be great. :)

Comment: One thing i noticed is that you are using placeholders to display data which are actual values of each field. using the `value` property of the input would be more relevant than using the `placeholder` one i think.

Comment: The value input is working better, but it's not displaying the information still. And thanks for your previous comment ;)

Comment: `$db = mysqli_connect(");` - is ugly.  I am sure it's just a mistake in the question.  But it's breaking the color coding.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix fixed

Comment: Not sure why you would want them as placeholders and not the value, but you should not be using `_REQUEST` and you should be checking if the form was posted before doing any of this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request

Comment: Shouldn't $id=$_POST['export']; be $id=$_POST['id'];, and if you are sending a _POST request, use _POST in place of all those _REQUEST, keep things organized!

Comment: Still haven't got it working. please if anyone can help that would be great.