# How to POST data from value of input if its exist in echo

Tags: php, post

I have a input inside of `<form action="include_php/update.inc.php" method="POST"> </form>`like this

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="new-username" value="<?php echo $result['user_name']?>">
<input type="text" id="password" name="new-password" value="<?php echo $result['user_password']?>">
```

And i am trying to read value of this input to check something. Here is the Post Codes.

When i try to only update my password. It goes first if even if there is a data inside of it.

```
$userName=$_POST['new-username'];
$userPassword=$_POST['new-password'];
    if($_SESSION['userName'] !== $userName){
        $sql="UPDATE users SET user_name='$userName' WHERE user_id='$id'"; 
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['userPassword'] !== $userPassword){
         $sql="UPDATE users SET user_password='$userPassword' WHERE user_id='$id'"; 
         $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        header("Location:http://localhost/talktoworldx/Anasayfa/account/index.php#success=update");
    }
```

But `$userName` has already value from database but it return nothing.
and it becomes like this `if($_SESSION['userName'] !== "" )`and it goes first if and change username to empty.

Maybe i am making really small mistake here but i couldnt figure out this.

So how can i send this value as POST method ?

Comment: `<form>` be default makes a GET request, not POST. You need to specify `method="POST"` in your form element to use POST.

Comment: One other option, if it fits the need, I recently learned of is to use PHP's $_REQUEST superglobal. You can read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: using `$_REQUEST` is a bad Idea as it can be overridden by `$_COOKIE` on some PHP applications.  See. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` first.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: It's kind of a "sticky wicket"  Something that would be great to use, but has all kinds of hidden pitfalls.   Generally I just avoid it.  `A sticky wicket (or sticky dog, or glue pot) is a metaphor used to describe a difficult circumstance.`

Comment: It may be stupid to ask but is `<?php echo $result['user_name']?>` empty ?

Comment: @RomainB. no data is exist in there

Answer (score 2):

Try with method attr of `form` set as `post`

```
<form method="post" action="url">
 <input type="text" id="username" name="new-username" value="<?php echo $result['user_name']?>">
</form>
```

**FOR php**

To validated the post data before

```
$userName=isset($_POST['new-username']) ? $_POST['new-username'] :''; 
if(!empty($userName){
 //do all stuff
}
```

Comment: @FurkanAkgün ok.What is the action ? can you post you form markup

Comment: are you sure.you could add this code in `include_php/update.inc.php` page

Comment: Yes i am . Also it goes in if because empty!=somename. then it makes user_name=empty in database

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell me the output :

```
  if(isset($_POST['new-username'])){

         $userName=$_POST['new-username'];  }

       else { $userName='default'; }

        if($_SESSION['userName'] !== $userName){
            $sql="UPDATE users SET user_name='$userName' WHERE user_id='$id'"; 
            $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      header("Location:http://localhost/talktowo
       rldx/Anasayfa/account/index.php#success=update");
      }
       else {
                echo 'something';
            }
```

Comment: it does same thing with my code. it works ican change the username but the point is  if($_SESSION['userName'] !== $userName) becomes true and i can change it but when there is "elseif" and if dont make any changes in username it still goes this if and skip elseif's