# PHP Extract Value From Request URI

Tags: php

I am working with a paypal checkout in php
after successful postback from paypal I am getting all transaction details using `print_r($_REQUEST, 1);`
with this piece of line it is saving full bunch of array data like below

```
Array
(
[route] => payment/pp_standard/callback
[mc_gross] => 130.00
[invoice] => 42 - sala uddin
[protection_eligibility] => Eligible
[item_number1] => Product 14
[mc_fee] => 5.37
[txn_id] => 8BX904469F430674P
)
```

I need to get only `[txn_id]`
How can I get only `[txn_id]` from above

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is an array. `$_REQUEST["txn_id"]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually `$_REQUEST['txn_id']` makes more sense...

Comment: [Don't use $_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request) to be on safer side.

Comment: @arkascha what do you mean ?

Comment: @Cid A question of style (readability) and performance. Though indeed it is minimal here :-)

Comment: How is the performance increased ? Because a double quote weights twice a single quote :p ?

Comment: Thanks its working with $_REQUEST['txn_id']

Comment: @Cid it is likely negligible speed wise for Mithus app but best practice is to use a single quote since double-quote further looks to interpret variables inside the double-quotes. see [php quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: @Cid @vivek_23 is correct, you should use `$_POST['txn_id']`, as someone could inject data in the URL.