# Checking if either of two statements are true

Tags: php, if-statement

I am checking if a variable 'auth' is set on either _POST or _GET and want two different actions. I have managed to get it working with if / else but it looks ugly and wasteful?

If POST isn't set, check GET. If GET is set, do nothing <- that part doesn't look right?

```
if ( !isset( $_POST[ 'auth' ] ) ) 
{
  if (isset( $_GET[ 'auth' ] ) ) {
    //do nothing

  } else {
    //redirect
    header( 'Location: https://google.com' );
    exit();
  }
}
```

Is there a whole new approach here? Like check both, if neither are set go to redirect, if ONE is set continue with page?

```
if(isset($_GET['auth']) xor (isset($_POST['auth']))) {
    //do nothing
}else{
 //redirect
 header('Location: https://google.com');
 exit();
}
```

^ if these are acceptable statements, what should be in the 'do nothing' section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply like using `&&` :

```
if(!isset($_GET['auth']) && !isset($_POST['auth'])) {
  header('Location: https://google.com');
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Could potentially be reduced to just `!isset($_REQUEST['auth'])`.

Comment: @El_Vanja  yes it can be, but it has own draw bags (As it includes cookie as well) : [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143042/4248328)

Comment: Yes, but that's true only of outdated versions. From the docs: `Note that the default distribution php.ini files does not contain the 'C' for cookies, due to security concerns.`; either way - that's why I've said "potentially". It depends on the environment.

Comment: @El_Vanja  agreed on that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the null coalesce (`??`) to chain the various values and default to null of nothing found, then check for null...

```
$auth = $_POST[ 'auth' ] ?? $_GET[ 'auth' ] ?? null;
if ( $auth == null )
{
    //redirect
    header( 'Location: https://google.com' );
    exit();
}
```