# what exactly is $_REQUEST[$K] in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$_REQUEST[$k] = isset($_GET[$k]) ? $_GET[$k] : $_POST[$k];
```

or

```
$_REQUEST[$k] = isset($_POST[$k]) ? $_POST[$k] : $_GET[$k];
```

Which is the case,reason?

Comment: *(suggested reading)* [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request) and [Does $_REQUEST have security problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149118/does-request-have-security-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.request) is the union of `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` where [*variables_order*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) and since PHP 5.3 [*request_order*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) defines the order.

The default order is GET, POST, and then cookie. That means POST parameters overwrite existing GET parameters and cookies overwrite existing POST and GET parameters.

Answer (score 1):

ini directive "variables_order" is believed* to affect $_REQUEST, see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

*"believed" because i never used either that or $_REQUEST itself.

Comment: You are correct, it does work like that in practice; however I agree that $_REQUEST itself is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

$_REQUEST is simply the array that PHP puts all of the GET and POST and COOKIE parameters into, with precedence in that order in the case of conflicts.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php