# Why the $_REQUEST variable is considered insecure?

Tags: php, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does $_REQUEST have security problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149118/does-request-have-security-problem)

Does anyone have verifiable citations on this? What would be the roundabouts for the security holes?

Comment: Because it [combines](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) the  contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small post that you can read about why:

http://devlog.info/2010/02/04/why-php-request-array-is-dangerous/

From that page:

> **Question:** Why is $_REQUEST insecure?
>
> **Answer:** Because it combines COOKIE as well as GET and POST, and the COOKIE data always takes precedence creating the possibility for dangerous "sticky" variables.