# PHP newbie - how to get the value from the drop down

Tags: php, mysql

I started PHP yesterday,
 and I want to know how I get the value from the drop down that I have to pass to the function. OK I got that part already. but I can't seem to call the assignment line below. instead, it just prints it out.

```
<?php include '../../view/header.php'; ?>
<div id="main">

<h1>Organization and their details</h1>

<br>
    //PRINTS THE LINE BELOW, NOT ASSIGNING TO $VIEW4
$view4 = get_view4($_POST["org_name"])
<?php echo $_POST["org_name"]; ?>
<table>
        <tr>

get_view4($org_name)
```

Comment: You need a form and post it.

Comment: You need to wrap everything in a `<form>` tag, and set some method to actually submit (either POST or GET) the data to your account.

Comment: I think you would need to start from the beginning. Your question on the `for` loop, which is actually a `foreach` also seems to indicate you don't have a lot of knowledge of HTML neither, which is not bad as such, but will complicate your task in learning PHP if you ask me...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a form along with the select box then when you just submit the form then you can access the dropdown value with $_REQUEST.

Comment: Don't use request if you know the method.

Comment: Yes right but request is for both get and post you can use get and post based on form method.

Comment: Thanks @Ravi Sharma I updated my question again. I can't seem to call the assignment. Instead it just printed it out..

Comment: @RaviSharma see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149118/does-request-have-security-problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `POST` in your form, you should use `$_POST['org_name']` and if you're using `GET` in your form, you should use `$_GET['org_name']`

Comment: Thanks. Am I doing it right?(updated post) how do I access the value outside the form? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method='post'>
<select id='dropdown' name='dropdown' >
<option value='test'>test</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='button'>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {

$dropdown = $_POST['dropdown'];

}
echo "$dropdown";
?>
//outcome should be test
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want a form, you'll have to get around and make a jQuery function to get the value. I suppose just adding form would be easier for you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.